# Password Expiration

Tags: security, passwords

I would like to now if there is way to "rollback" a password reset in salesforce (because otherwise the security token would also be reset and this is not desired).

Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to avoid a security token reset on end user passwords changing at expiration date? or on api-type user passwords?  If the latter case, you can avoid having api client users from having their password expire at all

Comment: I am interested in both, that the password remains the same.

Comment: ? a user changes their password and you want the password change not to happen?

Comment: Yes, I want to cancel the reset password action an that it not take place,, for example lets think that an admin clicked the reset paasword for a user and this admin decides that we doesnt want this to happend because that requires to generate another token and this is not desired

Comment: this is not possible

Comment: Thak you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

The security token will always reset when the password is changed. Setting the same password again won't give you the same security token.

Instead, give your API user(s) a distinct Profile.

Then, on that profile, set  "Password Never Expires" to true under "Administrative Permissions".

As an alternative to using a distinct profile you could create a Permission Set with "Password Never Expires" and assign that to the user.

---

I don't believe the user can opt-out of [an admin initiated password reset](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=resetting_and_expiring_passwords.htm&language=en_US). Nor is there any UI mechanism for the admin to recall the reset.

Raising a support case might be a possibility. It's a bit of a long shot and you would need a good justification for doing so. Most likely it would be easier to just update the password, get the new security token and not press the button again for that user.

Comment: Hello thank you for your replay, i will put this scenario to you. Lets think that an admin clicked reset paasword for a user and then he dicides that he doesnt want to reset and a sort of invalidate the reset and that the user continous with the same password, there is a way to accomplish this?. Thank you